Does temperature affect the outcome probabilities of a loaded die from a classical statistical mechanics perspective?
I know from classical statistical mechanics that the probability for a system to have energy E is proportional to $exp(−/_T)$.
Now, suppose I have a cube-shaped die whose center of mass does not coincide with its geometric center, so each face has a slightly different potential energy (due to gravity) when resting on the table. In theory, that means one face (the one with the lowest center-of-mass height) has a lower potential energy than the others.
Does this imply that at different temperatures T, the probabilities of landing on each face would follow something like $exp(−_{i}/k_{B}T)$, and thus certain faces might be favored more at certain temperatures?
If so, is this effect at all observable (even in principle) for a typical die throw in real life, or is it so small that it’s effectively negligible? How can one quantitatively estimate the magnitude of such an effect?
Any insight or references to analogous situations in statistical mechanics would be greatly appreciated!

Offhand, I would think that loaded die would always favor the one biased side, but the bias may increase with thermal expansion as the distance from the center to the CG increases. Also, statistical mechanical formulae including the very notion of temperature are only defined for large ensembles of units, not a single item

This is a good opportunity to understand how probabilities in statistical mechanics work.

I know from classical statistical mechanics that the probability for a system to have energy E is proportional to $\exp(−/_T)$

Not exactly. In classical statistical mechanics, we consider an (imaginary) ensemble of identically prepared copies of the system we are interested in. We imagine that each system is in contact with a heat reservoir, which you may think of as a very large (formally, infinitely large) second system with which our systems of interest are constantly exchanging random amounts of energy.
When I say random, an alarm should go off in your mind because I haven't told you which distribution that random behavior follows. One of the critical results in classical statistical mechanics is that if every possible configuration of the system + reservoir is equally likely (a fundamental postulate of statistical mechanics) then the probability that the system alone is in some particular configuration $x$ with energy $E[x]$ is proportional to $e^{-\beta E[x]}$, where $\beta$ is a property of the reservoir which relates to how many additional reservoir states become accessible as you increase the amount of energy it has.
So to summarize, we have an ensemble of identical copies of our system of interest which are constantly and randomly exchanging energy with a thermal reservoir. Within that formally infinitely large ensemble, the fraction of systems which are in some configuration $x$ at any moment in time is given by $e^{-\beta E[x]}/ Z$, where
$$Z= \sum_{y\in \text{conf}}e^{-\beta E[y]}$$
and the sum is over all possible configurations of the system. From this frequentist definition of probability, we then switch to a Bayesian picture and say that for an individual system about whose history and current state we have no knowledge, this is the probability that it occupies each possible configuration.

Does this imply that at different temperatures T, the probabilities of landing on each face would follow something like $exp(−_{i}/k_{B}T)$, and thus certain faces might be favored more at certain temperatures?

No, because this is not the dynamics which was described above. What you would need is a die which was constantly being "kicked" by its contact with a thermal reservoir which a well-defined temperature.  The temperature you are reading on the thermostat in your house is not what is being talked about here.
One might imagine that the die is sitting on a plate which is made to vibrate in an effectively random way (i.e. not just up and down, not just at a single frequency, etc). That plate would then be able to kick the die into different configurations. Even though it is not a thermal reservoir in the standard sense, it seems plausible that we might be able to assign it an effective temperature based on how much time the die spends on each face. Loosely speaking, more aggressive vibrations would correspond to a higher temperature and more uniform probability distribution.
There are some caveats here - for instance, the dynamics of a die flipping from one face to another add a potentially complicating factor, since it is in some sense easier to make a die roll from one face to an adjacent one rather than to flip over completely.

If so, is this effect at all observable (even in principle) for a typical die throw in real life, or is it so small that it’s effectively negligible? How can one quantitatively estimate the magnitude of such an effect?

No, because once again a single die roll does not generate a thermal probability distribution. A weighted die doesn't have a uniform probability distribution either, but precisely what that distribution actually is for a typical roll is something you'd have to measure empirically.

Let's consider first kinetic energy of dice. Let's take that its mass is 5 grams ans it moves with 0.1 m/s. How large should be a temperature to get this from a thermal energy? Well $mv^2/2 \sim k_B T$. This gives $T\sim 10^{17} K$. In the units used in particle physics this is $\sim 10 TeV$, this us about hundred times larger than the temperature of electroweak phase transition.
So, the macroscopic degrees of freedom of a dice are definetely not thermalized at current temperatures (and any dice would long be destroyed before you could thermalize them) so you shouldn't expect that you can use Boltzmann distribution to predict the results of the throw.

Thanks for the detailed answer. As temperature increases, higher-energy states become more accessible, which effectively washes out small energy differences, making the probability distribution more uniform. So it’s not that we need some huge temperature to ‘see’ a thermal effect..

...Therefore I think your explanation, assuming very high temperature situation, is not valid.
